# How can I add a menu screen that loads first to my Phaser.js game?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

Im trying to add a simple menu to my Phaser game that loads first, then once someone clicks on a button the game actually starts. I can figure out how to add the buttons later, I just cannot figure out how to add the menu screen. Ive researched quite a few ways online on how to get this done but none have worked for me. I've also tried breaking the code up into different states but that didnt work for me either. Maybe I was doing it incorrectly. Can someone show me correct way to add a menu to my game that loads before the actual game does?

```
<!doctype html> 
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.1.1/dist/phaser.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
           body {
                margin-top: 45px;
                margin-left: 250px;
                background-color: black;
            }

            .page-title {
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<script type="text/javascript">

//CONFIGURE GAME
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 300 },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update,

}
};

var player;
var stars;
var bombs;
var platforms;
var cursors;
var score = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var scoreText;

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
game.state.add('title', title);
game.state.start('title');


//PRELOAD FUNCTION
function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('sky', 'phaser_assets/sky.png');
    this.load.image('background', 'phaser_assets/background.png');
    this.load.image('ground', 'phaser_assets/platform.png');
    this.load.image('star', 'phaser_assets/star.png');
    this.load.image('bomb', 'phaser_assets/head1.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 100 });
    this.load.spritesheet('trump', 'phaser_assets/trump.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 100 });
}



//CREATE FUNCTION
function create ()
{
    //  A simple background for our game
    this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    //  The platforms group contains the ground and the 2 ledges we can jump on
    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
    //  Here we create the ground.
    //  Scale it to fit the width of the game (the original sprite is 400x32 in size)
    platforms.create(400, 568, 'ground').setScale(2).refreshBody();
    //  Now let's create some ledges
    platforms.create(600, 400, 'ground');
    platforms.create(50, 250, 'ground');
    platforms.create(750, 220, 'ground');
    // The player and its settings
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'trump');
    //  Player physics properties. Give the little guy a slight bounce.
    player.setBounce(0.2);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}



//UPDATE FUNCTION
function update ()
{
    if (gameOver)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(-200);
        player.anims.play('left', true);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        player.setVelocityX(200);
        player.anims.play('right', true);
    }
    else
    {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
        player.anims.play('turn');
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
    {
        player.setVelocityY(-330);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, you must define the condition for the game to be considered "loaded". For example when the preload() function is completed. So just render a very light menu instead of the game, as if instead of the game there were only the menu. Once the functions responsible for the loading of the menu are over, preload the game. You might want to visualize a progress bar (define a metric, like n bytes / n bytes tot). Once you are done, render the button to start the game.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently trying to do this with a function. However, I guess the better question would be how to work with different scenes within Phaser. Id eventually like to add a boot, preload and menu screen which seems like it should work fluently within Phaser, but I just cannot seem to figure out how to make one screen connect to the next screen using scenes.

Comment: Have you checked the examples? http://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=scenes/&q=